# How to use Plone 4.1.4 collective.documentviewer to OCR tiff images?

Tags: python, plone, tesseract

I wish to use tiff image with collective.documentviewer to perform OCR on the .tif /tiff images. Please let me know the detailed steps to do so. At the moment I am embedding the tif image into a pdf and uploading into the plone site and of course the document viewer does the OCR on this pdf very well. But I would greatly appreciate if the images of this type can be uploaded directly for OCR and also the preview for this image extensions are supported.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1320237/user, what I have asked is very clear. I am talking of using collective.documentviewer with Plone where tif images can be uploaded directly for preview, and for performing OCR using this add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate the Image content type as an available type in the control panel document viewer settings.

[image: control panel screenshot annotation]

You can't use the plone Image type, it has to be a normal File for it to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/627308/vangheem The type 'Images' is not available in the list. Is there a way to add it in this available list for auto layout file type? Iam using documentviewer 2.2.1 on plone 4.1.4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/627308/vangheem Thanks a lot! This works like a charm with tif images also except that the search and the text(OCRed text) tab of the documentviewer cannot detect the content of the tif file, but the plone site search can detect the text string contained in the tif file. As you said the image needs to be uploaded as 'File' only and not as a plone image type.